# Помощь в понимании кода ассемблера

Tags: c#, ассемблер, дизассемблирование

Есть код на C#, который открывает порт COM1 и в переменную "a" заносится значение - открыт ли порт.

```
SerialPort _port = new SerialPort("COM1", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
_port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
_port.Open();
bool a = _port.IsOpen;
```

Вот кусок кода ассемблера, собственно строка исходного кода + код ассемблера. Больше всего интересует код ассемблера _port.isOpen:

```
bool a = _port.IsOpen;
02B12EB3  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-40h]  
02B12EB6  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx  
02B12EB8  call        052D9954  
02B12EBD  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch],eax  
02B12EC0  movzx       eax,byte ptr [ebp-4Ch]  
02B12EC4  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax
```

И вопросы:

```
mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-40h]
```

Это я так понимаю: в памяти со смещением [ebp-40h] содержится значение _port.IsOpen, для которого инициализируется 32-битное машинное слово, которое заносится в регистр ecx

```
cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx
```

Не могу понять зачем происходит это сравнение.

А дальше, я так понял код ассемблера на выполнение команды присвоения?

Comment: Собирайте отладочную версию софтины и загружайте ее в IDA. Ида подцепит PDB и покажет гораздо более информативный листинг чем то, что вы привели: тут даже переменных на стеке не распознано.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотрите, что делает этот код.

```
; bool a = _port.IsOpen;
02B12EB3  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-40h]
```

`dword ptr [ebp-40h]` означает 32-битное слово в стеке, в области локальных переменных (т. к. отрицательное смещение от `ebp`) текущей процедуры. Судя по всему, это загрузка указателя `_port`. Это похоже на Майкрософтовское соглашение вызова [`__thiscall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ek8tkfbw.aspx), когда указатель `this` передаётся в метод через регистр `ecx`.

```
02B12EB6  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx
```

Это просто: проверка `ecx` (то есть, `_port`) на `null`. В случае, если `ecx == 0`, произойдёт access violation, который будет превращён в `NullReferenceException` кодом, который обрабатывает аппаратные исключения. Результат сравнения игнорируется, сравнение нужно только чтобы как-то обратится к `[ecx]`. (В C#, в отличие от C++, доступ по нулевому указателю — не undefined behaviour, поэтому эта проверка необходима. Впрочем, часто компилятор может *доказать*, что она не нужна, и выкинуть её.)

```
02B12EB8  call        052D9954
```

Это вызов метода [`IsOpen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.ports.serialport.isopen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). `IsOpen` является не полем, а свойством, и получение его значения отображается на вызов метода-геттера.

```
02B12EBD  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch],eax
```

«Маленький» результат вызова (а у нас это `bool`, [1 байт](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx)) обычно возвращается в регистре `al`. Весь регистр `eax` кладётся во стековую переменную по адресу `dword ptr [ebp-4Ch]` (судя по всему, неоптимизированный код).

```
02B12EC0  movzx       eax,byte ptr [ebp-4Ch]
```

Мы конвертируем байт `al` в 32-битное слово, извлекаем таки `bool`. Команда `movzx` расширяет байт нулями до 32-битного слова. Зачем? Дело в том, что доступ к 32-битным словам быстрее, чем к отдельным байтам, вот мы и выделяем под `bool`-переменную 32-битное слово.

```
02B12EC4  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax
```

Ну и записываем результат на место.